# How to update many documents using UpdateManyAsync

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following method to update a document in MongoDB:

```
public async Task UpdateAsync(T entity)
{
    await _collection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter => filter.Id == entity.Id, entity);
}
```

Which works fine - I was just wondering if anybody has an example of how the `UpdateManyAsync` function works:

```
public async Task UpdateManyAsync(IEnumerable<T> entities)
{
    await _collection.UpdateManyAsync(); // What are the parameters here
}
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`UpdateManyAsync` works the same way as `update` with `multi: true` in Mongo shell. So you can specify filtering condition and update operation and it will affect multiple documents. For instance to increment all `a` fields where `a` is greater than `10` you can use this method:

```
var builder = Builders<SampleClass>.Update;
await myCollection.UpdateManyAsync(x => x.a > 10, builder.Inc(x => x.a, 1));
```

I guess you'd like to replace multiple documents. That can be achieved using [bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) method. If you need generic method in C# then you can introduce some kind of marker interface to build filter part of replace operation:

```
public interface IMongoIdentity
{
    ObjectId Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can add generic constaint to your class and use `BuikWrite` in .NET like below:

```
class YourRepository<T> where T : IMongoIdentity
{
    IMongoCollection<T> collection;

    public async Task UpdateManyAsync(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        var updates = new List<WriteModel<T>>();
        var filterBuilder = Builders<T>.Filter;

        foreach (var doc in entities)
        {
            var filter = filterBuilder.Where(x => x.Id == doc.Id);
            updates.Add(new ReplaceOneModel<T>(filter, doc));
        }

        await collection.BulkWriteAsync(updates);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @mickl answer, you can not use x=> x.Id because it is a Generic 
Use as below:

```
public async Task<string> UpdateManyAsync(IEnumerable<T> entities)
{ 
     var updates = new List<WriteModel<T>>();
     var filterBuilder = Builders<T>.Filter;

     foreach (var doc in entities)
     {
          foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())
          {
              if (prop.Name == "Id")
              {
                  var filter = filterBuilder.Eq(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(doc));
                  updates.Add(new ReplaceOneModel<T>(filter, doc));
                  break;
              }
          }
     }
     BulkWriteResult result = await _collection.BulkWriteAsync(updates);
     return result.ModifiedCount.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you go by Bson attribute:

```
public async Task UpdateManyAsync(IEnumerable<TEntity> objs, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) 
{
var updates = new List<WriteModel<TEntity>>();
var filterBuilder = Builders<TEntity>.Filter;

foreach (var obj in objs)
{
    foreach (var prop in typeof(TEntity).GetProperties())
    {
        object[] attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true);
        foreach (object attr in attrs)
        {
            var bsonId = attr as BsonIdAttribute;
            if (bsonId != null)
            {
                var filter = filterBuilder.Eq(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(obj));
                updates.Add(new ReplaceOneModel<TEntity>(filter, obj));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

await _dbCollection.BulkWriteAsync(updates, null, cancellationToken);
```

}